# Formas de chamar imagem no no wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Seguinte

```
        <div class="site-branding">
              <img src="http://sitedementirinha.com.br/wordpress/wp-content/themes/alizee/images/logo1.png"/>
        </div>
```

tenho esse código em um tema do Wordpress, e mas ele não carrega o logo.png em nem uma navegador ou dispositivo móvel, ja troquei a imagem, um 10 vezes e não tive resultado se alguém puder me dar um outra alternativa fico grato.

Comment: Pode passar o link do site? Seria mais facil propor uma solução...

Answer (score 1):

Quando se trata de wordpress existem coisas para facilitar isso por exemplo isso já chamaria seu tema tente assim

```
<?php $template_directory = get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
<div class="site-branding">
   <img src="<?php echo $template_directory;?>/images/logo1.png"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode existir um bloqueio no .htaccess ou nas permissões do diretório.

Uma dica que gosto muito de utilizar em casos como este é:

1. Faça upload da imagem dentro do Wordpress através do menu de mídia.
2. Copie a url gerada para a imagem carregada.
3. Utilize este link dentro do tema.

Se isso não funcionar então nenhuma imagem vai funcionar dentro da sua instalação, pois é assim que as imagens são inseridas nos posts, thumbnails, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verifique o caminho da imagem, acesse o link da logo diretamente no navegador e veja se a imagem abre ou não.
2. Veja as permissões da pasta onde se encontra a imagem, normalmente usa-se `644`, mas em caso de testes pode colocar `777` ou `755`.
3. Existem diversas formas dinamicas de adicionar imagens no template, o Anderson citou uma. Pode encontrar outras na [Documentação do Wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/)
4. Verifique arquivos como `.htaccess`, ele pode estar fazendo algum `redirect` errado (difícil acontecer, mas vai que...)
5. Limpe o cache do site e do navegador, principalmente se estiver usando algum plugin de otimização de velocidade.